# octave vectorization 2 for loops

Tags: vectorization, octave

how could this loop be vectorized? I have to multiply a vector and its transpose to generate a matrix of n * n to then subtract it by the identity matrix, but it takes too long to generate the matrix.
Thanks

```
vi1=i1'(:)';  --->vector
vi1t=i1'(:);  --->vector transpose


z=length(vi1t);
x=length(vi1);

for n=1:z
  for m=1:x
    ma1(n,m)=vi1t(n)*vi1(m)
  end
end

#m1=ma1-eye(rows(ma1)); not implemented yet
```

Comment: `ma1 = vi1 .* vi1t`?

Comment: can be, now in less than 1 second did what it took in hours, I have to control the data. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .* operator!

**For your example:**

```
a=i1'(:)';

aT=i1'(:);

A = a .* aT
```

Also there is other operators that behave the same way as ./

Here is a useful cheatsheet I use sometimes:

https://gist.github.com/obstschale/7320846
*--Credits belong to the author: https://gist.github.com/obstschale*